# Catch resetModel events from QAbstractItemModel in QAbstractItemView?

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt5, qlistview, qabstractitemmodel

The functions `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` emit the signal `modelAboutToBeReset()` and `modelReset()`. I want to react on those in the subclassed `QAbstractItemView` but I cant find any hints in the documentation. Are there any slots/protected funtions to handle those at all?

Comment: Any particular reason for not defining your own slot and link it to `modelAboutToBeReset`?

Comment: KISS. If Qt provides it, I wont duplicate it. I guess I found some kind of solution. `void QAbstractItemView::reset() [virtual slot]` seems to do what I want.  But I am not sure if it is the 'correct' way.I would appreciate any cofirmations.

Comment: It depends on how you *want to react*. What do you want to do? Clear the items?

Comment: I want to select the first item and update the geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it is the right way but overriding reset() works:

YourSubclassOfQAbstractItemView.h:

```
void reset() override;
```

YourSubclassOfQAbstractItemView.cpp:

```
void YourSubclassOfQAbstractItemView::reset()
{
    QAbstractItemView::reset();
    updateGeometry();
}
```